# Protocol-relative 'image' URL in Schema.org

Tags: image, url, schema.org, protocol-relative

My image addresses look like this:

```
//cdn.shopify.com/....jpg
```

Google SDTT:

[image]

Although there are no indicated errors, if I paste image address in a browser, I will get:

> Your file was not found

Do I need to add `https:` in order to make it work?
Should my developer fix image address?

Comment: 1) I removed the first question, because it had nothing to do with the second one. Please ask it in a separate question. -- 2) Please include the syntax/line that you use for specifying the `image` property.

Comment: [Related question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/99537/absolute-or-relative-local-url-in-schema-org-json-ld)

Answer (score 0):

**When entering** a network-path reference (`//example.com/foo`) into a browser’s address bar, you don’t end up on a HTTP(S) page, because the browser doesn’t know the base URI. [See details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46748795/1591669)

**When linking** a network-path reference from a HTML page, a base URI can be established. Standard-conforming user agents (browsers etc.) are capable to understand such references.

For structured data (e.g., with Schema.org), make sure that you correctly specify that the property value is a URI reference, otherwise it would be interpreted as string. So in Microdata and RDFa, you have to use elements like `a`/`img`/`link`/etc., in JSON-LD you have to use `@id` (but your `@context` might pre-define that the values of certain properties are by default `@id`s).